Local maxima of $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - xy$ subject to $x^2 = 16$, $y^2 = 16$
Given the problem below:
Write down the Lagrangian when the problem is to maximise the function
$$
f(x, y)=x^2+y^2-x y
$$
on the set
$$
\{(x, y):-4 \leq x \leq 4,-4 \leq y \leq 4\} .
$$
Use the Kuhn-Tucker first-order conditions to identify all the candidate local maxima, and determine which of them are indeed local maxima.
I used the fact that the set is equivalently defined by $x^2 \leq 16, \ \ y^2 \leq 16$ to reduce to 2 constraints.
When both constraints bind, I thought I found local minima at $(x,y) =(4,4), \  (-4,-4)$ and (global) maxima at $(x,y) = (-4,4), (4,-4)$ , but the solutions I have report this:
$x=+4, y=+4, \lambda=\mu=\frac{1}{2}$ therefore local max at $(+4,+4)$
$x=-4, y=-4, \lambda=\mu=\frac{1}{2}$ therefore local max at $(-4,-4)$;
$x=+4, y=-4, \lambda=\mu=\frac{3}{2}$ therefore local max at $(+4,-4)$;
$x=-4, y=+4, \lambda=\mu=\frac{3}{2}$ therefore local max at $(-4,+4)$.
That would mean that every single point is a local maximum when the constraints bind, which seems counterintuitive since the function is not constant. Also, I tried to check the Bordered Hessian but I got an inconclusive result, since the first leading principal minor has determinant 0 and the number of variables equals the number of binding constraints.
I got the same results as the solution for the two Lagrange multipliers, but didn't think this was conclusive since the problem is not a convex optimisation problem so the KKT conditions should not be sufficient.
Do $(x,y) =(4,4), \  (-4,-4)$ count as both local maxima and minima? Are they not minima at all? What? Thanks  :)

Let's examine the objective function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-xy$
First derivative would be $\begin{bmatrix}2x-y \\ 2y-x\end{bmatrix}$
The second derivative would be $\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ which suggest that $f$ is a convex function and hence the problem is a convex optimization problem.

Let's study a border to understand what is going on, when $x=4$, the function becomes, $y^2-4y+16=(y-2)^2+12$, a quadratic function in $y$ that is symmetrical about $y=2$. when $y=4$, the objective value is $16$, when $y=-4$,  the objective value is $48$. $f(4, -4) > f(4,4)$ and we can see that $(4,4)$, and $(-4,4)$ can be both local maximum though the value is different.

A visualization can help to understand. I have plotted the contour plot. The $4$ corner points are indeed local maxima and they are not minima.  Here is the desmos link

